# How to select all SELECT tag in form and check their value in JQUERY

Tags: jquery

how can i select all the SELECT tag inside a particular form and check if their selected value is equal to 0??

```
 if($('[name="1"]').val() == 0  || $('[name="2"]').val() == 0 || $('[name="3"]').val() == 0 || $('[name="ifpDimension"]').val() == 0) event.preventDefault();

<select name="1" class="form-control">
    <option value="0">PLEASE SELECT</option>
    <option value="Personal">PERSONAL</option>
    <option value="Community">COMMUNITY</option>
    <option value="Teaching">TEACHING</option>
    <option value="Social">SOCIAL</option>
</select>
```

i can do that in this code but is there a easier and cleaner way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
var len = $("select").filter(function () {
    return this.value == 0;
}).length;

if (len) { 
    // something is having is 0 value 
    //  return false 
}
```

Comment: **"WooW..!! One of the greatest application i have ever seen in my life.."** This was the reaction i exhibited after seeing your link.

Answer (score 1):

you can find the option elements by value(which is 0 in your case) which are selected. if object returned has length greater than 0 then do the needful :

```
if($("form select option[value=0]:selected").length>0){
    //some select not selected
}
```

Comment: `[value=0]` just checks the `value` attribute which is usually not set for `select` elements: http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/0aLv8n9n/ . On the other hand `$('select').val()` checks the `value` property which is not always equal to the corresponding attribute.

Comment: @PeterKA: it should be good when done based on option selected value http://jsfiddle.net/dg5wbxnn/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code. Let's say your form is:

```
<form id="myForm" ....>
```

You can use `.filter()` to return `select` elements with a zero value. If you want to execute some code when there's no select with value zero, use the following:

```
var form = $('#myform'),
zero_select = form.find('select').filter(function() { 
    return this.value == 0; 
});
if( zero_select.length === 0 ) {
    ......
}
```

To execute code when at least one `select` element has a zero value use:

```
var form = $('#myform'),
zero_select = form.find('select').filter(function() { 
    return this.value == 0; 
});
if( zero_select.length ) {
    ......
}
```

Comment: i tried this but its not working, i think it's because of the ===